# Transitioning container registry to gcr.io finalise step failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

I have completed the steps to transition my container registry images to artifact registry.

But on the last step (Finalise), I keep getting this error with no extra information on how to solve it: `Failed to finalise gcr.io routing: Precondition check failed.`

Finalize Button Image:
[image: finalise routing button]

Comment: The finalize option has been removed. How are you attempting to finalize and where are you seeing this as a transition step?

Comment: @James the finalise step is in the settings after routing to artifact registry, there's a Finalize button that appears as the last step. It shows a popup which indicates that after continuing with the step one cannot go back to using container registry. I added an image to the question that shows the button.

Comment: You can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/setup-gcr-repo#gcloud_3) which states that to go back to the container registry. Even you can check with this [Link](https://serverfault.com/questions/1084874/unable-to-finalize-container-registry-transition-to-artifact-repository)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya, the command is to re-enable container registry but I am not trying to re-enable container registry. I want to move to artifact registry and I have done the step to route traffic to artifact registry, it's just there's a finalise step which is giving me an unknown error as described in the question earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We removed the finalized state. Looks like we missed a button, but we'll remove it soon too

(I'm an engineer working on Artifact Registry for Google)

Comment: Ok noted. That means after routing, the process is completed right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can also delete the GCS bucket used by GCR once you've copied over the data you want and are sure you don't want to go back